# Returning a local array corrupts array data

Tags: c++, arrays, sfml, corruption

I am generating random noise by creating an array of pixels, that I then use to create an image. The code works, and the compiler shows no problems, except a warning that says: `warning: address of local variable 'tmp' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]`

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

sf::Uint8* getPerlinArray(unsigned int width, unsigned int height){
    sf::Uint8 tmp[width * height * 4];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < width * height * 4; i+=4){
        sf::Uint8 value = rand() % 256;
        tmp[i] = value;
        tmp[i + 1] = value;
        tmp[i + 2] = value;
        tmp[i + 3] = 255;
    }

    return tmp;
}

sf::Image getPerlinImage(unsigned int width, unsigned int height){

    sf::Uint8* arr = getPerlinArray(width, height);

    sf::Image img;
    img.create(width, height, arr);

    return img;
}

int main(){

    //Set random seed.
    unsigned int seed = time(NULL);
    srand(seed);

    //Create window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "Random Noise");

    sf::Image img = getPerlinImage(64, 64);

    sf::Texture txt;
    txt.loadFromImage(img);

    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(txt);

    while (window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)){
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Green);
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result I get is this:

[image: 1]]

You can clearly see that the noise-generator works, but the array seems to get corrupted as wee see at the bottom of the image I am drawing. I found that the "corruption" occurs when I am returning the array. If put `sf::Uint8 tmp[width * height * 4]` (and I define `width` and `height`) outside the `getPerlinArray` function, so that `tmp` is global, the array does not get corrupted and the program works like it should. Is there a way to return a local variable(array, in this case), without it getting corrupted?

Comment: Code warning = problem!

Comment: You cannot safely return pointers to local variables. Return a value, such as a vector object.

Comment: In the first function an array lives only within a function. You should create array: `sf::Uint8* tmp = new sf::Uint8[width * height * 4];`

Comment: @MichaelO. And what about deleting it? Why not suggest vector?

Comment: @NeilKirk Since `tmp` is returned, it can be deleted later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return dynamically allocated memory, ideally from a RAII'd container:

```
std::vector<sf::Uint8> getPerlinArray(unsigned int width, unsigned int height){
    std::vector<sf::Uint8> tmp(width * height * 4);
    //identical code goes here.
    return tmp;
}
```

and then:

```
auto arr = getPerlinArray(width, height);

sf::Image img;
img.create(width, height, arr.data());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Under my original answer, Michael O. suggested to define the variable like this: `sf::Uint8* tmp = new sf::Uint8[width * height * 4];`. Both your code, and his, work. Would you care to explain how they differ? :-) I am new to C++ programming, and i don't quite understand the memory management.

Comment: Our code is functionally identical, but mine has the added advantage that the deletion of the allocated memory will be handled automatically. If you used Micheal's code without adding a `delete[] arr;` after the img.create(), you would have had a memory leak. My way is safer, and considered "better" by modern standards.

Comment: I agree with @Frank. If you still want to use my variant, add `delete[] arr;` after `img.create(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a language like C++ you have many options

1 - Instead returning the value you can take it like a parameter.

```
void getPerlinArray(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, sf::Uint8* ){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < width * height * 4; i+=4){
        sf::Uint8 value = rand() % 256;
        tmp[i] = value;
        tmp[i + 1] = value;
        tmp[i + 2] = value;
        tmp[i + 3] = 255;
    }

    return tmp;
}

sf::Image getPerlinImage(unsigned int width, unsigned int height){

    sf::Uint8 arr[width * height * 4];
    getPerlinArray(width, height, arr);

    sf::Image img;
    img.create(width, height, arr);

    return img;
}
```

2 - You can extend the scope of the dangling pointer. Forexample you can make it global. Just move `sf::Uint8 arr[width * height * 4];` to global scope if width*height is known in compile time.

3 - You can use C++ and use std::vector instead of C arrays. So your code will look like

```
std::vector<sf::Uint8> getPerlinArray(unsigned int width, unsigned int height){
   std::vector<sf::Uint8> tmp(width * height * 4);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < width * height * 4; i+=4){
        sf::Uint8 value = rand() % 256;
        tmp[i] = value;
        tmp[i + 1] = value;
        tmp[i + 2] = value;
        tmp[i + 3] = 255;
    }

    return tmp;
}

sf::Image getPerlinImage(unsigned int width, unsigned int height){

    std::vector<sf::Uint8> arr = getPerlinArray(width, height);

    sf::Image img;
    img.create(width, height, arr.data());

    return img;
}
```

There are many other solutions like dynamic allocation with malloc, new etc..